# Unity UI-Animations possibilities

Tags: animation, unity, ui-design

I'm doing some stuff with UI-Animations the past days, but I never figured out, whether it is possible to do stuff like this with Unity : https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/107759/screenshots/1623679/menu.gif

I would guess, that this is not possible, but maybe I just missed some feature :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several way's you could attempt to do this:

1. Create a sprite containing the individual frames ([tutorial](http://michaelcummings.net/mathoms/creating-2d-animated-sprites-using-unity-4.3) for animating it)
2. Use the GIF directly in Unity ([script and tutorial](https://www.bytesthatbit.me/2016/03/18/animated-gif-texture-unity3d/))
3. Use three [Line Renderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) and animate their properties

Currently there is no support direct for animated Vector graphics in Unity.
 Even though there are [plugins](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38258) to import SVG into Unity, they don't support Animated SVG.
Maybe [this](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38258) will work, but I don't know.

Comment: I've written a Script, where you can define a path with bezier curves and animate along this path. Such things like animated icons should work with this :)

Answer (score 1):

Well there isnt a ready feature for these types of animation. But you can certainly do it with Unity. The Top and bottom bar seem to be just rotating and scaling a bit. For the middle one you will need to substitute it with another sprite that is a circle and  use the radial fill feature to simulate the motion. Another approach would be do to a frame by frame animation. Perhaps make the animation in After Effects or something and export all the frames.

Comment: Yeah I mean that was just an example, because I wanted to know, whether you can animate lines like that, but the after effects approach would have been my best idea too :D

Comment: Just an idea, which came in my mind: Couldn't you theoretically append a trail renderer to a dot and animate the dot, so you could achieve all the smooth line animation stuff?

Comment: In theory this approach should work too. Good idea but you will have to try it yourself. My guess is that its going to be rather difficult to make the trail renderer look like you want it.

Comment: Yeah sure, but thanks for the clarification, that such things are rather difficult to make in Unity :)